# What does -- do in Excel formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to decipher some Excel formulas and I see some stuff like SUMPRODUCT(--Left(...)...)

What is the -- doing? Naturally seems like decrementing to me but couldn't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The double-dash is known as a double unary operator.

Try this link:  [Why use -- in SUMPRODUCT formulae](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/formulae/doubleneg.html)

Specifically:

> SUMPRODUCT() ignores non-numeric entries. A comparison returns a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) value, which is non-numeric. XL automatically coerces boolean values to numeric values (1/0, respectively) in arithmetic operations (e.g., TRUE + 0 = 1).
>
> The most efficient way to coerce the value is first to apply the unary minus operator, coercing TRUE/FALSE to -1/0, then applying it again to negate the value, e.g., +1/0.

A single unary operator (-) coerces **true/false** values into **-1/0**.  By using the double unary operaor, we coerce the values again to **1/0**.

Comment: What a nice hack!  Something of an Easter Egg, in that it's not easy to find until you find it  ;-)  Others have searched and either not found it, or haven't backlinked to this question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289771/count-how-many-true-values-appear-in-an-array-within-a-formula-in-excel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130598/how-to-apply-a-logical-or-to-an-array-in-excel

Answer (score 7):

The unary operator (-) is a shorthand method to convert a true/false statement into -1/0.

A single operator will convert -(true) into -1, so a double unary operator is used to convert that back into 1:

```
-(-(true)) = -(-(1)) = 1
-(-(false)) = -(-(0)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SUMPRODUCT for a while and have always used the `*` symbol instead of the `--`. I'm sure I asked the same question you've asked, but I can't remember the reason they gave me, but I was told that there wasn't really a need for `--`as sumproduct managed itself quite well without the it.

Anyway, `=sumproduct(()*()*()*())` has always worked for me, and it's less confusing.

Comment: -- can coerce a single array at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean values TRUE and FALSE in excel are treated as 1 and 0, but we need to convert them. To convert them into numbers 1 or 0, do some mathematical operation. The Unary operator negates the boolean (math operation), hence, converts the boolean to number. Same works in TRUE * FALSE = 0