# Simple Excel Array Example Comparing Only The First Value of Input

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate with an Array Formula (in Cell D2) what i'm calculating long-way in cell D11. The issue i'm having is that it appears my Array Formula is not evaluating the inputted array one-by-one. As an example, I want the second comparison that the formula does to be the following:

Check if ([B7>0] AND [C7=0]) and, if so, return D7.

But I think it's only checking to see if every value in the column B array is >0 and if every value in the column C array is =0.

The screenshot below details my problem. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze4gm.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array formula, you can use

```
=SUMIFS(B6:B10,B6:B10,">0",C6:C10,0)
```

Array formulas don't like AND. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130598/how-to-apply-a-logical-or-to-an-array-in-excel). This array formula would work

```
=SUM(IF(B6:B10>0,IF(C6:C10=0,B6:B10)))
```