# Count how many True values appear in an array within a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, boolean

In a formula such as this:

=if(Match(TRUE, Index(($B$5:$E$5)-$A5,,)=B$4,0),1,0)

where the return value is 1 if the difference of any of the values in range B5:E5 and cell A5 is equal to the value B4 (Relative Reference).

Is there any way to, instead of matching to the true values, count the true values?

Something Like:
=countifs(Index(($B$5:$E$5)-$A5,,)=B$4,TRUE)

The former formula above will simply return 1 despite the number of true values and I also want to see the number of times the true value occurred in a separate formula.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$5:$E$5-$A5=B$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Hilarious, I just posted my own answer below with he same type of logic, but you got there first and a little cleaner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very nice!  I have crosslinked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130598/how-to-apply-a-logical-or-to-an-array-in-excel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-do-in-excel-formulas

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(R17C3:R19C3-(R[-9]C4/1440),,)=R7C)*1)
```