# COUNTIF combined with OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, worksheet-function, logical-or

I want a formula for count how many *True/Yes/Si* are in the range.
If A1 is not empty i want to count.
I don't know how to put the 3 parameters in the formula

```
=IF(A1="";"";COUNTIF(A2:A5;"TRUE")) <- I need to add Yes and Si.
```

**Edit:**

I forgot to say that I want `or`, not `and`. (I will never have "True", "Yes" and "Si" in the same range). I want something like that:

```
IF(A1="";"";COUNTIF(A2:A5;"True" or "Yes" or "Si"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add multiple countif's - `=if(A1<>"",countif(a2:a5,"Yes")+countif(a2:a5,"Si")+countif(a2:a5,"True"),"")`

Comment: Why don't you want to test it to see for yourself?

Comment: @user4563174 - I am sort of confused, it should work regardless.  If there's a "true" and no "si" or "yes", it'll count 1. If there's "true" and "si" it'll count 2.  Do you want to look for ONLY "Si" or ONLY "true" (as defined by a value in a cell, say A1)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go a bit crazy you can use this *array formula* (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(A1="","",SUM(--(A2:A4={TRUE,"Si","Yes"})))
```

Comment: I think it is CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for array formulas.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss My excuses... :) Thanks!

Comment: That's awesome @ZygD , I haven't seen the {} used within a formula before.  Learned something new :thumbsup:

Comment: @user3578951 That's a bit geeky :D

Comment: @ZygD - is your use of the `--` and the array called anything in particular, with regards to VBA? I would like to learn what you're doing with those, but am not sure what I'd look up.  "Double subtraction"??  In my mind, those two '-' would cancel out and therefore be positive - but if you remove them from the formula, it doesn't work anymore.  What kind of technique/formula is that called?

Comment: I don't know the exact term for it. `--()` just explicitly transforms logical values to numeric (`True` -> `1` and `False` -> `0`). Without it, the array formula would not work. Excel often implicitly does this transformation, but not in array formulas AFAIK. This notation has nothing to do with regular math.

Comment: Okay, double minus signs (double unary operator) actually [has something to do with math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel). I've just learned something new too ;)