# Matching numeric strings of different length in Excel

Tags: excel, matching, vlookup

I have 2 data sets that I would like to match based on a common field which contains a numeric string. Since the string of one data set is contained in the string of the other (e.g., **9876** to be matched with 12**9876**0), I'm using a combo of `LEFT()` (or `RIGHT()` ) and `VLOOKUP()`. The problem with this approach is that I have to rewrite the formula manually when the numeric string changes the number of digits and the position of the substring (e.g., **987654** to be matched with 12**987654**). Any insight on how to do the match more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following array formula¹ will produce the correct wildcard results from a lookup column of true numbers.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&H5&"*", TEXT(H$8:I$10, "0"), 2, FALSE)
```

In the following image, note that this has a side effect of converting the returned value from a true number to text as well. A [double-unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel) could take care of that.

[image: vlookup_wildcard]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard in your `VLOOKUP`.

`=VLOOKUP("*9876*", H8:I10, 2, FALSE)`

OR

`=VLOOKUP("*"& B4 &"*", H8:I10, 2, FALSE)`

Rather than looking for a cell that equals 9876, this will look for a cell containing 9876 and remove the need for `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, etc.

Comment: I believe that wildcarding a true number essentially turns it into text and `"9876" <> 9876`.