# Range.FormulaArray causing error in specific cases

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, formula

I have a piece of code which puts an array formula in a range. It is throwing runtime **error:1004 "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class".** But when I paste the same formula in the cell and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter everything works fine.

```
strFormula = "=IF(SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423))=0,TEXT(,),SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423)))"

shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").FormulaArray  = strFormula
```

The problem occurs when the IF condition was inserted. So without the IF the following code works fine:

```
strFormula = "=SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423))"

shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").FormulaArray = strFormula
```

**Note:** If I use `shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").Formula` then there is no error but the result is incorrect

Comment: You don't need all of those double unaries if you are multiplying the boolean conditions against each other. The act of multiplication does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A [Range.FormulaArray property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx) can only have 255 characters and yours was showing 248. A few mistypes might have brought it over the limit.

```
strFormula = "=IF(SUM((A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*" & _
                     "(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*" & _
                     "(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*" & _
                     "(Data!$E$2:$E$1423))," & _
                 "SUM((A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*" & _
                     "(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*" & _
                     "(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*" & _
                     "(Data!$E$2:$E$1423))," & _
                 "TEXT(,))"   '<~~ 226 characters
shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").FormulaArray = strFormula
```

As I mentioned in comments, the [double-unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel) operator is not necessary when multiplying boolean conditional statements against each other. The act of the mathematical operation makes the boolean ► numerical conversion.

**[Alternatives](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)**

In Excel Options, Advanced, Display options for this worksheet you can turn off Show a zero in cells that have zero value.

Any of the **Accounting** number formats will display a hyphen in place of a zero value.

A custom [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) can be generated that simply does not display zeroes at all. One of the simplest would be,

```
General;General;;@
```

Comment: Have you considered simply not displaying a zero rather than running that array formula twice just to get a zero-length string in place of a zero?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. What I did to solve the problem is to first declare the range object, then use .FormulaArray on the range.

Using C#:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range eRange = wks.Range[wks.Cells[1,1], wks.Cells[20, 20]];
eRange.FormulaArray = $@"=some formula";
```