# Create a formula that gets that selects a range from a named table and returns the product

Tags: excel

I have a named table Table_inflation, which is on a sheet called "Inflation Rates". It holds each years inflation factor, as below:

[image]

On another sheet "Lines Detail" I have a cells that I would like to populate with the compounded inflation rate DL5 -> onward:
[image]

To find the which column of inflation data to target I use the first word of the sheet name e.g. "Lines Detail" becomes "Lines".

To find the range of years I'll use the starting year e.g. 2015 and the end year will be the first number in the column title e.g. if "2017 - 2018" use 2017.

My question is if I have these variables, how can I put them together into a formula in Row 5 of "Lines Detail"? E.g. get the inflation data and multiply them together.

[Update]

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(Table_Inflation[Lines], MATCH(INT(LEFT($DL$6,4)), Table_Inflation[Year], 0)):INDEX(Table_Inflation[Lines], MATCH(INT(LEFT(DL$6,4)), Table_Inflation[Year], 0)))
```

So as you can see I've set the first index to always find the first column title with 2015 in it and convert the string to an integer.

I can almost use autofill and drag the formula copying it to the other years, however it alters the Table_Inflation column name to next column name e.g. I drag the formula over one cell to the right, 'Lines' become 'Points' and 'Year becomes 'Lines'

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(Table_Inflation[Points], MATCH(INT(LEFT($DL$6,4)), Table_Inflation[Lines], 0)):INDEX(Table_Inflation[Points], MATCH(INT(LEFT(DM$6,4)), Table_Inflation[Lines], 0)))
```

Is there a way to set these so they don't change?

Comment: A formula has no acces to the sheetname, so this should be somewhere on the sheet. And how can the startingyear be found? Or is it fixed at 2015?

Comment: Ok first point noted. Second point yes is fixed to 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>- To find the range of years I'll use the starting year e.g. 2015</sub>
>    <sub>- how can I put them together into a formula in Row 5 of "Lines Detail"? E.g. get the inflation data and multiply them together.</sub>

The [PRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PRODUCT-function-8E6B5B24-90EE-4650-AEEC-80982A0512CE) will multiply each cell in a range against each of the other cells in that range.Think of it as [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) without the addition.

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to get the start and end of the range. For example, these two formulas are exactly the same thing:

```
=SUM(A2:A9)
=SUM(INDEX(A:A, 2):INDEX(A:A, 9))
```

If you are wondering, that trick does not work with [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [HLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) functions. Those only return the value from the lookup, not the cell reference.

In 'Lines Detail'!CZ5 as a standard formula,

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(Table_Inflation[lines], MATCH($CY$2, Table_Inflation[year], 0)):INDEX(Table_Inflation[lines], MATCH(--LEFT(INDEX(6:6, 1, COLUMN()), 4), Table_Inflation[year], 0)))
```

[image: table_inflation]

As you can see, I've put your 'starting year' in 'Lines Detail'!CY2. Remember that the [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22) returns a string that looks like a number and `2015` does not equal `"2015"` so a [double-unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel) operator is required to convert the results to a true number that the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) can locate in Table_Inflation[year].

Comment: I understand this is perfect, I have tweaked it a little so that the constant 2015 always comes from CY6 by using the '$' and using the INT() function to convert the string to numeric. I have posted an update above, I can almost use the autofill to drag/copy the formula into the rest of the cells, just one small glitch.

Comment: Select the range with [ctrl]+[shift]+→ and tap [ctrl]+R (aka *Fill Right*) rather than dragging.

Comment: This method works when in the spreadsheet, however if I do it with VBA via Selection.FillRight it doesn't, any ideas?

Comment: Put the formula in all of the cells at once like `Range("DL5:DS5").Formula = "=PRODUCT(INDEX(Table_Inflation[lines], MATCH($CY$2, Table_Inflation[year], 0)):INDEX(Table_Inflation[lines], MATCH(--LEFT(INDEX(6:6, 1, COLUMN()), 4), Table_Inflation[year], 0)))"`