# Find first nonempty cell in the column Excel

Tags: excel

It is very strange that I want to find the first non-empty cell in a column
I use

`=MATCH(1,P:P<>"",0)`

`P:P<>""` become the (0,0,0,0,1,...) column, then it should be the index of first 1, but actually it does work in the excel, even I use  `=MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(P:P<>""),0)` or `=MATCH(TRUE,P:P<>"",0)`

I have the correct solution:

`=MATCH(1,INDEX((P:P<>"")+0,0,1),0)`

why can't we use `P:P<>""` replace `INDEX((P:P<>"")+0,0,1)`?

by the way, here `(P:P<>"")+0` is translate `T/F` into `1/0`? Why not use `ISNUMBER`?

Comment: For future reference, TRUE is one (e.g. **1**) on a worksheet and FALSE is zero (e.g. **0**) when used mathematically (e.g. (A1=6)*(A2=7) equals **1** when A1 equals 6 and A2 equals 7. The formula equals zero for all other possibilities. . For all intents and purposes, FALSE is zero and **anything that is  not FALSE is TRUE** (but an error code still overrides everything else).

Comment: If you think `+0` is weird, go google **[double unary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel)**.

Comment: @Jeeped so why are we only allowed to use `INDEX((P:P<>"")+0,0,1)`  instead of `P:P<>""`, I think they are same mathematically.

Comment: INDEX converts an expression into an array of values. If you want to leave the INDEX out, you'll need to array enter the forumla with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter so that the expression evaluates into an array by itself.  Google Excel Array Formulas for more information

Comment: Yes, they are the same mathematically but only one is boolean and mathematical, hte other is only boolean.