# adding numbers in front by determining first number Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a new number in front of them, depending on the first number

- If first number is 3,5,7,9 then add in front 2
- Else add in front 6

With Macro button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbod8.png)

Comment: re: '*I have a column of telephone numbers*' - Your image (recently added through an edit) shows 5 columns of telephone numbers.

Comment: my Fault  can you help ?

Comment: Just as soon as I see the code that you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a formula to recreate the list in a new column, use this:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2)="3",LEFT(A2)="5",LEFT(A2)="7",LEFT(A2)="9"),2&A2,6&A2)
```

Comment: I am using this with macro function

Comment: I've just submited another answer using VBA. Take a look!

Comment: can you take a look i added picture, its harder because its not a collum.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
=--(IF(OR(--LEFT(A1,1)={3,5,7,9}),2,6)&A1)
```

Comment: Im really new to this what is ( -- )?

Comment: That is commonly known as a [double unary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel).  It can be read as "minus negative" if preferred.  Its purpose here is to convert strings into numbers (i.e. convert the string `"2"` into the number `2` in order to perform numerical comparisons)

Comment: @AnGr - Of course, googling [what is -- in excel](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHZL_enCA733CA733&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+--+in+excel) could have told you that in less time than it took to type out your question let alone getting [tigeravatar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2665425/tigeravatar) to answer.

Answer (score 2):

A Select Case statement makes an easy job of  multiple comparisons.

```
dim rw as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    for rw = 2 to .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
        select case int(left(.cells(rw, "A").value2, 1))
            case 3, 5, 7, 9
                .cells(rw, "A") = int(2 & .cells(rw, "A").value2)
            case else
                .cells(rw, "A") = int(6 & .cells(rw, "A").value2)
        end select
    next rw
    .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).numberformat = "0 000-0000"
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via VBA, run the following sequence of code:

```
Sub AddNumber()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Strt As String
        i = 2 'your first row index with data
        j = 1 'the column index your list is located (e.g. column A)

    Do While Cells(i, j) <> ""
        Strt = Left(Cells(i, j), 1)
        Select Case Strt
        Case 3, 5, 7, 9
            Cells(i, j) = 2 & Cells(i, j)
        Case Else
            Cells(i, j) = 6 & Cells(i, j)
        End Select
        i = i + 1
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can i adjust this Code with Pic I added ?