# Excels' MID() function returns wrong "type" of data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've encountered a situation where MID() is returning the expected value, but it seems to be the wrong "type". For example, imagine you have a simple table of characters and their width in inches...

```
Char | Width
A    | 0.3465
B    | 0.3144
C    | 0.3478
...
```

In cell A1, I have the phrase `F1-40` (my desired serial number).

In cell C2, I have the formula `=INDEX(Widths,MATCH(C1,Chars,0))`.

When I **manually** type `1` in C1, the formula in C2 displays the width of that character as expected.

When I use a formula to find the character... `=MID(A1,2,1)`... C1 *displays* the correct character (still `1`), but:

- If the character is a letter, INDEX/MATCH works fine.
- If the character is a number, INDEX/MATCH **fails** (???).
- If the character is a number *and* I wrap the MID() like so: `VALUE(MID())`, INDEX/MATCH works fine.
- If the character is a letter *and* I wrap the MID() with `VALUE(MID())`, INDEX/MATCH **fails**.

Surely there is a way to accomplish this without knowing beforehand if MID() will return a number or letter?

Thanks,

-B

Answer (score 2):

MID returns text. If it looks like a number, it's text-that-looks-like-a-number, not a real number. You cannot use text-that-looks-like-a-number to find a match in a column of real numbers. Thankfully, there's the [double unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel) or double minus that can covert text-that-looks-like-a-number to a true number.

```
=--MID(A1,2,1)
```

However that will throw an error if you are trying to convert true text (e.g. *abc*) to a number so an IFERROR wrapper must be applied to return either a true number (if possible) or text.

```
=iferror(--MID(A1,2,1), MID(A1,2,1))
```

Comment: If you haven't changed the default cell alignment of the cell containing that formula, you will notice right alignment for numbers and left alignment for text. This confirms either a true number or text.